# str.replace between 2 special characters retaining special characters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the number that is in-between the special characters which I have found a way to do so but I would like to retain the special characters after the change.

As seen in the snippet below it is removed

```js
var day = 24;

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){

var str = "09/23/2020";
str = str.replace(/\/.*\//, day);
console.log(str);
day++;

}
```

Would appreciate if anyone knows a fix

edit : the day variable is not fixed

Comment: Just use `.replace(…, '/24/')`?

Comment: That would be a easy way to do it but the day variable would be changing each time as this is part of a code that is increasing the date count (e.g. 24, 25, 26)

Comment: `'/'+day+'/'` !

Answer (score 2):

Bergi's solution is easier and better but here is another ugly solution

```
var str = "09/23/2020";
var day = "24";
var array = str.split("/");
array[1]=day;
console.log(array.join("/"));
```